# How long can I stay in Germany after quitting my Blue Card job?

Tags: visas, germany, australian-citizens, blue-card

I am Australian and as such from a non-EU country and hold a German "Blue Card EU" which is tied to a job I had in Germany. I worked there for 1 year but stopped working there last week.

I am now in the process of applying for a Swiss working permit and I intend to move there and begin working there when that is finished. I was told that it could take more than 3 months though to get the working permit, which is kind of worrying because I am only allowed 90 visa-free days in the Schengen zone.

Therefore my question is: **how long can I stay in Germany now that I have quit the job for which I had my Blue Card?** Citizens of my country get 90 visa free days, so there's that, but do I get any "extra" time thanks to my blue card? It surely musn't expire as soon as I quit my job, right?

Comment: You would get better answers on our [expatriates.se] site, which is intended for questions about living and working abroad.

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to stay 3 months after losing your job, afterwards when your Blue Card may be withdrawn:

> #### What happens if I lose my current job while an EU Blue Card holder?
>
> If this happens, then you are allowed to stay unemployed for 3 months in order to find a new job otherwise your EU Blue Card may be withdrawn and you may be asked to leave the hosting country.

([EU Blue Card FAQ page](https://www.eu-bluecard.com/faq/))

Comment: Note: '*may be* withdrawn'.

Comment: This seems unrelated to what I have. It says Australians are ineligible, though I am Australian and indeed a blue card holder (I have it in my hand right now and it says it is a "Blaue Karte EU"), so I don't know what the website is talking about but it's not what I have

Comment: @houlahaj you never said you were Australian, please clarify your question in the future. Thanks

Comment: Yes I should have said that first, sorry. Thanks for the reply. I wasn't criticizing what you said, rather the website you supplied, which says Australians are ineligible for the "Blue Card EU" which is certainly doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Your source appears to be a third-party site, not official government information.

Comment: Can you take a look here? https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173313/changing-jobs-on-blue-card-in-germany